# Is converting a BSW to Ethernet jack ends possible?

Tags: wiring, ethernet

I have a spare ex. 5 pair, gel and armored BSW between my home and my shop app. 120’ away. Range ext. don’t work. Can I convert BSW to Ethernet jack ?

Comment: What does BSW stand for?

Comment: Buried Service Wire? The stuff telco uses for phone service? No, telephone wire is too low in quality for ethernet.

Answer (score 3):

You can certainly put some ends on the cable and find out what happens. Chances are it'll be CAT3 cable at best and the Ethernet may link at only 100 Mbps or 10 Mbps (if at all). But maybe that's good enough for you.

If it's not good enough you might look at some of the G.hn equipment. The G.hn standard can be used to bridge Ethernet over AC powerline, coax, *or twisted pair cable* up to 2 Gbps. Most G.hn devices I've noticed support only one or maybe two of these physical media.

Failing that there are of course a multitude of wireless options in 2.4, 5, and 60 GHz unlicensed spectrums, or of course fiber.. But all of that goes well beyond the scope of your question.

Comment: Well, the OP is "Fiber Engineer", so odds are good he's familiar with fiber. Of course, that could be "wool fiber engineer" or "cotton fiber engineer" and he's in the yarn/fabric business, so who knows... :)

Comment: @FreeMan Optical fiber is the first thing I thought of, partially because of the nature of the question and also because I'm neck deep in a large fiber optic project myself. But you're entirely right: it could be a reference to engineering of textiles or even forest products!